# How to change the text color of action bar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I know there are very few questions already posted on this thing. I filtered almost every post, but no luck and I am not getting the result which I have to get. First I tried **code snippet#1**, everything worked fine as in the image1. But now I must change the actionbar background to light and dull color, so did it, the result is activity's title and items' titles are in white color which are barely legible. So, decided to change the text color, but didn't get how to change it with my present code in the styles.xml. If someone could help me in changing the text color with present **code(snippet#1)** itself, that would be very great. As I didn't get how to modify the present code, I Followed [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/srQAd4R8ckQ) and so now my code is **code snippet#2**, now my action bar completely goes weird making the home icon and app title disappear and displays only the item that is towards right like the **image 2**. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

**code snippet#1**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

**code snippet#2**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
         <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
```

**Below are my images:**

[image]

[image]

In the second image, title, icon and blue border line are disappeared. I have to show them because I am setting home enabled to true.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is the most recommended for customizing an ActionBar:

http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

its easy too.

If you only want to change some Text color/size, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="YOURTHEME" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
        <item name="textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'. showing this error in eclipse at <item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>. Please suggest

Comment: Got it working man. Can't wait to thank you and upvoting and accepting it. But can you please make sure that this will not differ as version changes? Because I have seen in some posts regarding the distortions in appearances in different versions.

Comment: It shouldn't differ. You might have read about ActionBarSherlock, thats why they recommend items both **with and without android: prefix**. But it would be great if you can give a link to 1 of those posts.

Comment: Sure, but I have to search again. BTW why without prefix for textcolor shows error?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you one suggestion regarding this action bar sherlock?

Comment: how about having a border around the action item?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc it didn't work for me on old android versions, even though i'm using ActionBarSherlock too. How could it be?

Comment: Never mind. found out I need to use actionMenuTextColor too. wonder how it worked for you guys. anyway, found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/sbCUTKk03Nw

Comment: @ Archie.bpgc, I am using your code to change the text color of Action Bar title, and it is working fine but it is also changing my Action Bar's color from Red to white. Can you help me to solve this please.

Comment: @SalmanKhan what is the parent you are using? have you tried actionbar theme generator from the answer?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc, i am using the same Theme as you have mentioned in your code

Comment: @SalmanKhan. My code is part of the theme. Not the whole style.xml code. Please use the theme generator to get the basic things like actionbar background etc and then customize what you wanted. I think you have missed `<item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_xxxx</item>`

Comment: @Archie.bpgc, I have used the same theme generator for backgrounds and all thats why I am saying that when i add this code to my style xml it is changing my background image of action bar to white.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc, where should I add this background tag in XML. Can you please explain it to me

Answer (score 2):

I used the link above from Archie.bpgc and created a style that used the Light - Dark Action Bar and that solved my problem by allowing me to pick the colors that I needed.

The above example did not work for me to change the text color.

The link: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to change the text color that is on the **Menu**, not the color of text that is in the **Title** in **ActionBarSherlock**.

When you use "**getSupportActionBar (). SetTitle (" My Title ")**" to style this text you should use the code of **@Archie.bpgc**. His answer is correct, but for having gone through this same problem, I believe that you are in need is the following code:

```
<style name="MyTheme.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

See that you simply exchange *parent =" TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.**Title** ">* by *parent = "TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.**Menu**"*>